# How can I customize doxygen's top link bar?

Tags: html, doxygen

I would like to modify Doxygen's top link bar from the standard bar (below)

[image]

to a customized bar, kind of like what Doxygen's documentation [site](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/starting.html) does. (below)

[image]

I've looked through the config file, but I haven't found anything. What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to add a custom Doxygen Layout file.

Run doxygen using `doxygen -l` to generate the default layout file `DoxygenLayout.xml`.
Then add it to your Doxyfile

```
LAYOUT_FILE = DoxygenLayout.xml
```

To change the top bar you want to change entries under `<navindex>`

More info on this: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout